# Azure IoT hub Node jS Number of retrys to sendEvent , set the timeout period

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-node-sdk

I am using MQTT protocol to send data . I have set NoRetry() as i wanted to go into callback if any network failures are there. but it is coming only after 4 min . can i change that timeout period to some milli seconds when i am in NoRetry() . Reason is that in case if figured out the error in sending the message i can save data locally and send when connectivity comes back.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a client.SetOptions({keepalive: 10}). The number is the number of second between keep alive packets. Do the setOptions before the open/connect occurs. Also set all of your options at the same time.

Note of course that this will generate more network traffic. Normally the keepalive pings are at 180 seconds.

Comment: i tried by doing client.setOptions({keepalive : 10} ) ;
var client = clientFromConnectionString(connectionString);
client.setOptions({keepalive: 10});
client.setRetryPolicy(new NoRetry());
client.open(connectCallback);
But it did not worked out i am getting failure in sending the message only after 5 minutes
Log Here with time

Comment: status: MessageEnqueued Fri Nov 02 2018 11:18:18 GMT+0530 (IST)

### Here i disconnected with internet
i am disconnected Fri Nov 02 2018 11:24:15 GMT+0530 (IST)

this is error sendeventNotConnectedError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN cyientiothub.azure-devices.net:8883 Fri Nov 02 2018 11:24:15 GMT+0530 (IST)

you can see that both sendEvent and disconnection from IoT hub reported to me only after 6 min

Comment: @TonyErcolanco   Firstly Thank you for responding .
I am using is-internet-available module to check whether internet connectivity is there or not ? As it is taking 400ms for this every time i am sending message , i wanted to avoid this , is there any way i can know that client is connected or not ? Asynchronously . 

And for suppose my internet will be unavailable for more than 5-6 hours and it gets connectivity back , then will automatically connectivity happens or i need to do client.close() then cleint.removeAllListner() and cleint.open( connectionstring )